# ActiveRecord query works fine on sqlite but fails in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-activerecord

Folks,

I have an activerecord statement that works fine on my development machine which uses sqlite3 but when I run this same code in production which uses MySQL this fails. The code is below:

```
avail = Account.count( :conditions => "room_name == 'jail' AND account_state IS NULL")
```

When I run this in production I get a MySQL syntax error:

also for this statement I see the same behavior:

```
_acct = Account.where( "room_name == 'jail' AND account_state IS NULL").order("updated_at ASC").limit(1)
```

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

I believe MySQL uses single equal sign whereas sqlite understands both = and ==

try

```
"room_name = 'jail' AND account_state IS NULL"
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

here's your problem:

```
room_name == 'jail'
```

MySQL expects only a single =.